# copy selected file from an input on electron app form

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm, electron

I have this form

```html
<form>
  <input type="file" name="idp" id="idp" onchange="uploadFiles();"/>
</form>
```

When the user chooses a picture I need to copy it to a specified folder and store its full name into a variable to save it into the database.

I've tried this code:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const { dialog } = electron;    // electron.remote; (if in renderer process)
const fs = require('fs');       // module that interacts with the file system
const path = require("path"); 
function uploadFiles(){
    // opens a window to choose file
    dialog.showOpenDialog({properties: ['openFile']}).then(result => {

        // checks if window was closed
        if (result.canceled) {
            console.log("No file selected!")
        } else {

            // get first element in array which is path to file selected
            const filePath = result.filePaths[0];

            // get file name
            const fileName = path.basename(filePath);

            // path to app data + fileName = "C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\app_name\picture.png"
            imgFolderPath = path.join(app.getPath('userData'), fileName);

            // copy file from original location to app data folder
            fs.copyFile(filePath, imgFolderPath, (err) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(fileName + ' uploaded.');
            });
        }
    });
};
```

and it gives me this error message on the console:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showOpenDialog' of undefined
>     at uploadFiles 
>     at HTMLInputElement.onchange
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const { dialog } = electron;    // electron.remote; (if in renderer process)
```

It appears that you are calling this from a `renderer` process. Therefore you need to use `electron.remote` in order to access the `dialog` module (as the code example you are using above indicates).

It's worth taking the time to read up on the`main` and `renderer` processes in `Electron` – they are fundamental concepts that you will encounter over and over and they are especially important in [IPC messaging](https://www.christianengvall.se/ipcmain-and-ipcrenderer/)